# Excel formatting a list

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, text-formatting

I have a list of one column as follows:

```
x1
y1
[blank]
x2
y2
[blank]
x..
y..
[blank]
```

I need to get this formatted into:

```
x.. | y..
[blank]
```

What's the easiest way to accomplish this in excel or bash?

Comment: You have value X1, Y1, x & Y in Rows and you want to Format X,, I  Y..  are in columns!!

Comment: The question appears to indicate that the goal is X and Y in separate, adjacent cells.  The solution puts them in the same cell.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Found this formula online, accomplished what I needed!

```
=OFFSET(A$1,(ROW()-1)*2,0)&" "&OFFSET(A$1,((ROW()-1)*2)+1,0)
```